# $f ' \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ implies absolute continuity of $f$ on some subset of $\Omega$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, absolute-continuity

My question is if, $f' \in L^1(\Omega), \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ implies absolute continuity of $f$ on $\Omega$?

Maybe there is some trivial counterexample but I didn't find one. Thanks for help.

Comment: I think you misprint here, because it is very easy to find a function that is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but not absolutely continuous. For example, let $f(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}$. the indicator function over interval $[0,1]$. It is NOT even continuous.

Comment: Please update your question. Otherwise, it seems to be silly

Comment: You meant $f' \in L^1$ implies absolute continuity of $f$ (this is [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions) : $f$ is absolutely continuous iff there exists $g \in L^1$ such that $f(x) =C+ \int_a^x g(t)dt$)